# Surjectivity and Injectivity of a Constant Function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know why when both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linear (namely has a look of $ax+b$ where $a\neq0$) we have that $f\circ g-g\circ f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can't be injective or surjective.

As per my calculation $f\circ g-g\circ f$ represents a single constant, which seems to satisfy $x=y$ for $f(x)=f(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = ax+b$ and let $g(x) = cx + d$. Then let $h(x)$ denote the function

$$h(x) = (f\circ g)(x) - (g\circ f)(x) = a(cx+d) + b - c(ax+b) - d = ad + b - bc - d.$$

So you're right that this is a constant, and hence can't be surjective (since the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ has more than one point). You're confused about the definition of injectivity though. A function $h$ being injective means that whenever we have $h(x) = h(y)$, this will imply $x=y$.

This is not injective since $h(2) = h(3)$ but $2\ne 3$, for example.